# HTML with TailwindCSS memory leak

Tags: html, npm, firefox, memory-leaks, tailwind-css

Good day,

I am currently creating a simple image-gallery style CRUD website for the purposes of practicing Laravel and learning TailwindCSS. The problem that has been plaguing my project is an incredible memory leak that I cannot trace down. Whenever I refresh the page, the RAM usage grows by about 150 MB. This continues ad nauseam until my computer's memory is completely clogged up and I have to close the tab, which I then reopen and the cycle begins anew.

To be more precise, these are steps I take:

1. Open the page on localhost (127.0.0.1:8000 specifically);
2. Make some changes to the HTML (although unnecessary for the leak to appear);
3. Refresh;
4. Task Manager shows the Firefox process RAM usage increase by about 150 MB;
5. The tab continues to use RAM all the way to 3GB+, at which point I end the tab process;
6. Restore the tab;
7. Repeat steps 2-6.

I am using TailwindCSS 2.1.4 with Laravel 8.46 and Firefox 89.0.1. I have not compiled my TailwindCSS source file and my page currently contains HTML, CSS, and Blade directives. Checking the Memory tab in the dev tools, the number does not grow and stays the same with every refresh -- I have attached a screenshot of the tab:
[Memory tab of Firefox dev tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nvLa.png)

Where am I steering wrong? Additionally, perhaps there are more efficient ways to preview changes without refreshing the page every time?

Thank you for taking the time.

EDIT: I am also including my **webpack.mix.js**, **composer.json** and **packages.json** files:

webpack.mix.js:

```
 const mix = require('laravel-mix');
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources /css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);
```

package.json:

```
 {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "dev": "npm run development",
            "development": "mix",
            "watch": "mix watch",
            "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
            "hot": "mix watch --hot",
            "prod": "npm run production",
            "production": "mix --production",
            "build-css": "tailwindcss build cssSrc/styles.css -o public/tailwind.css"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
            "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
            "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
            "axios": "^0.21",
            "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
            "lodash": "^4.17.19",
            "postcss": "^8.2.1",
            "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
            "tailwindcss": "^2.1.4"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "colorette": "^1.2.0"
        },
        "name": "Practice",
        "description": "Practice website.",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "main": "webpack.mix.js",
        "directories": {
            "test": "tests"
        },
        "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "(my GitHub page)"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
        "bugs": {
            "url": "(my GitHub page)"
        },
        "homepage": "(my GitHub page)"
    }
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more informations about your App settings composer.json, package.json, webpack and more to give correct advice. there has so many reason.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but you could potentially try using the just-in-time mode for Tailwind CSS. It uses substantially less RAM than the normal mode. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode. May not solve your issue, though, but worth a try I think.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this has solved the problem completely. I wish I could mark your response as the answer, but apparently that is not possible for comments.